# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'BinaryTreeNode' and 'int'

Tags: python

**I'm trying to obtain the sum of even numbers in my class through % operator, but the result throws:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'BinaryTreeNode' and 'int'
```

My code is as follows:

```
class BinaryTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
        self.data = data #value node
        self.left = left #left child
        self.right= right #right child

#Resolution
#     1
#  2    3
# 7 5  6  7
root=BinaryTreeNode(1)
root.left=BinaryTreeNode(2)
root.right=BinaryTreeNode(3)
root.left.left=BinaryTreeNode(7)
root.left.right=BinaryTreeNode(5)
root.right.left=BinaryTreeNode(6)
root.right.right=BinaryTreeNode(7)    
def sumRecursive(root):`enter code here`
    if(root==None):
        return 0
    if root.data%2==0:
        m=root.data
    if root.left%2==0:
        n=root.left
    if root.right%2==0:
        b=root.right
    return m + sumRecursive(n) + sumRecursive(b)
tmp=sumRecursive(root)
print("La suma del arbol es %d" %(tmp))
```

Comment: `root.left` is not an integer. So, `if root.left%2==0` giving that error. Same for `if root.right%2==0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error is that your code is doing this: `if root.left%2==0:`. But `root.left`, as the message says, is a `BinaryTreeNode` which you can't take a mod of. Or it could be `None`, ditto.

You could do `if root.left.data %2 == 0:` to make that error go away, but that is unnecessarily complicated and will lead to difficulty, because as it stands your code only sets `n` and `b` conditionally, but calls `sumRecursive(n)` and `sumRecursive(b)` unconditionally, so you will end up with undefined local variable errors. So leave that test to the recursive call, which your function is doing already with `if root.data % 2 == 0:`, and do this instead:

```
def sumRecursive(root):
    if not root:
        return 0
    if root.data % 2 == 0:
        m = root.data
    else:
        m = 0
    n = sumRecursive(root.left)
    b = sumRecursive(root.right)
    return m + n + b

sumRecursive(root)
8
```

Comment: Thanks BoarGules , it helped me a lot, currently i can not cast  a vote because i am new but when i get 15 reputation i'll come back